# Searching in Dictionary of arrays in Objective C

Tags: ios, arrays, dictionary, search

I have a dictionary like as follow:

```
{
    125047 =     (
                 {name = "poet";},
                 {name = "singer";}
                 );
    125048 =     (
                {name = "ABC";},
                {name = "OGGI";}
    );
    125049 =     (
                {name = "Lovely";}
    );
    125050 =     (
                {name = "poem";}
    );
    125051 =     (
                {name = "zyx person";},
                 {name = "123 number";}
    ); 
}
```

i have to do searching with respect to name and reload to tableview.
I had previously worked on Array of dictionary but i'm stuck in dictionary of arrays.
I tried searching using for loop to each dictionary. but its took more time if this dictionary is bigger in size(more number of array in dictionary).

-Thank you.

Comment: Do you need the key, or just want to see if the dictionary contains the value?

Comment: Your data shows a dictionary containing arrays which contain dictionaries. And it isn't clear what your goal is. "Reload to tableview?" What does that mean?

Comment: Have a look at inline predicates in this post:
http://kickingbear.com/blog/archives/9. That uses KVC to kinda perform a fast inline predicate.